# Is it viable to generate electricity by pulling ions from water?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity

I'm reading *20,000 Leagues Under the Sea*, and it looks like it says the *Nautilus* generates electricity by pulling sodium ions from the water. This doesn't seem like it would be a viable way to generate electricity. Pulling the cations out of the water while leaving the anions would take energy, and because entropy in a closed system never decreases, and since the *Nautilus* isn't extracting any latent energy in the sodium, it should be impossible to get more energy out of this than you put into it. Is my assessment correct?

Comment: It says that the sodium is extracted via heat from coal. pt 1 ch 12: "I utilize the heat of coal from the earth." and pt 2 ch 10: "[The Nautilus] needs electricity to run, batteries to generate its electricity, sodium to feed its batteries, coal to make its sodium, and coalfields from which to dig its coal."

Comment: @Yorik That comment might be better as an answer, although I'm not sure the question is appropriate here.  In any case answers potentially get more reputation points than comments and we discourage answering in comments, so consider if your comment should be worked into an answer.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine just a clarification about the work of fiction which was the inspiration for the question. It isn't relevant to the actual question though.